# How do I wire a single phase 240v APC UPS from US split phase power?

Tags: 240v, ups

I want to wire in a 200/208/220/240v single phase APC UPS, the APC Smart-UPS RT 6000VA, there are both single and split phase versions of this, I have the single. It has the standard brown blue green wire going into it, and the manual mentions basically nothing on wiring it.

I am in the USA, where we have split phase, and my home has the standard 120v system. Is it possible, and if so how could I wire in the ups into my home? I have wired multiple 240v circuits before, for welders and table saw, but I have no idea how to accomplish it for a more "sensitive" device.
I have seen the possible solution of feeding in the two live wires, but I don't know if this equipment can tolerate that.

I have seen this question asked here about motors, but I'm asking about an APC brand UPS.

Here is a picture of the back connection.
[image: Connection panel]

Here are pics of the wiring I did to create an outlet for it:

[image: Wiring in the panel]

[image: Wiring at the receptacle]

[image: Open panel and the new receptacle]

[image: Closed panel and the new receptacle]

Comment: I've embedded the pics from a link in a comment on Harper's answer. Sometimes comments can disappear. Please [edit] to indicate if these were done before or after you asked the question. It doesn't change the validity of the question, but will help explain the timing to those looking later.

Answer (score 4):

Just wire it up like a table saw. Hot-Hot-Ground.

Never use the obsolete and dangerous NEMA 10 connector.

Whether you need neutral or not, a 4-wire NEMA 14 connector is always OK, and provides the most versatile socket (it will support 120/240V loads also).

If you don't need neutral, a NEMA 6 connector is just right. You can use black-white cable, and re-mark the white wire black with electrical tape.

Wiring from panel to socket should use normal in-wall wiring methods e.g. Romex in walls, or Wiremold surface conduit with THHN wire.   From plug to UPS should be flexible *cordage*, there may be pre-molded cords that are just right.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm still abit hesitant as to whether this will work or not, and I did post a similar question on the apc forums, but I don't really expect a response there. Could someone explain why it would be ok to do it this way, or have have seen it working with a ups? I went ahead and wired in the circuit, and I did include a neutral as suggested. Here are pics of that, yes the wire is oversized and I didn't ground the outlet box great yet: https://postimg.cc/gallery/ZnkqjcG

Comment: @super7800 in any metal box, the ground wire needs to go to the metal box *first*.  Once that is done, because of the type of domed cover and socket you used, the socket will pick up ground automagically from the box.  Now you just need a flexible cord with the appropriate plug and socket to connect to that wall socket and to the UPS.

Comment: @super7800 "Could someone explain why it would be ok to do it this way" – In short, the UPS needs two conductors with 240 V AC across them, and two hot wires (with opposite phases) are two conductors with 240 V AC across them.

Answer (score 0):

The green wire with the yellow stripe is ground, which will connect to the green or bare wire. The brown and blue wires are the hots, which will connect to the black and the red, or the black and the white of the red is not available. Which is which between the brown and the blue does not matter.